# how to do a create partial view inside a edit view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, bootstrap-modal

I can add a create partial view within a modal bootstrap so that it can add value in the table with a edit view of the field value ?

My create partial view

```
@model MVCLayout.Models.Table2

    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Cargo: ", new { style = "width:160px" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { style = "width:200px" })
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Percentual: ", new { style = "width:160px" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:200px" })
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Serviço: ", new { style = "width:160px" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Work, new { style = "width:200px" })
            </div>
            <br/>

            <p>
               <input type="submit" value="Save" />
           </p>

        }

        </p>
```

My Edit View

```
<html>
<body>
@model MVCLayout.Models.Table1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
    <div id="signup">
        <div class="rontainer">
            <div class="header">
                <div id="dock">
                <br>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AdmServicos", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Editar Servios</legend>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            @Html.Label("Código:", new { style = "width:160px" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { style = "width:55px", @readonly = "readonly" })

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Descrição: ", new { style = "width:160px" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, new { style = "width:550px", @readonly = "readonly" })
                        </div>


                        </div>

                        <br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    @{
                                        Html.RenderPartial("CreateTable2", Model.ID);
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I do this with a partial view or the best way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to add some sort of dialog where you want to load MVCLayout.Models.Table2 model in order to save it with the corresponding id of the MVCLayout.Models.Table1?

Comment: You can do this. Pass object of type Model2 in the overload of Html.RenderPartial or Html.Partial. The partial view will then render in your modal.

Comment: @SometimesCode when I step model it only from the post in Table1 and not in the post of table2 , how would the controller? could help me with an example?

Comment: @Gustavomacedo : sample example is in answer. Please let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

create a property of Table2 type in your Table1 Model like below :

```
public class Table1
{
  public Table2 table2 {get; set;}

//other properties of Table1 Model
}
```

Now in your Edit View:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
        @{

      Html.RenderPartial("CreateTable2", Model.table2);
          }
       </div>
```

Now in your Action of the Controller :

```
public ActionResult Edit(Table1 model)
{
var editPartialViewData = model.table2;
// Do whatever you want to do with this data

}
```